# Navigation doubts in Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am facing a different problem in navigation ,i have three view controllers,bookselectionview,chapterselectionview and verseselectionview,the bookselectionview contains books of Bible if we tap genesis it navigate to genesis chapterpage
and if the chapter is selected from the view it navigate to the corespondent chapters verse view,i have close button in chapter view and verse view if the user tap the verse close button it wants to pop to the corespondent chpterview,that is like the back button in the navigation bar,but i created the custom button for that,my problem is when i tap the back button it cress the application.this is my code 
in viewwillapper of the chpterview

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

```
 -(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
        VersusSelectionView *detailViewController = [[VersusSelectionView alloc] initWithNibName:@"VersusSelectionView" bundle:nil];

    //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.selectedChapter=[sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
    appDelegate.selectedChapterIndex=[sender.titleLabel.text intValue];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

the above code navigate t the verse page 
in versepage viewwillappear

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in verseselectionview closebuttonclick

```
-(IBAction)_clcikbtnclosetochptervew:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

when tapping close buon it pop the chpterview and crash the app.
any error in my code? please help me to do this.Thanks.

Comment: Please include a crash log when asking questions about your app crashing.

Comment: @jrturton my app crash in main "program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: Type `bt` in the debugger window to get a backtrace, this will tell you what was happening at the time the error was encountered.

Comment: @jrturton sir where in debugger window?i can't understand it.plz.thanks

Comment: The pane that pops up at the bottom of your xcode window, it will say `gdb` or similar in there with a prompt >. This is the debugger, it is your friend :)

Comment: #0  0x01b4609b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x06427f70 in ?? ()
#2  0x017b8d16 in CA::release_objects ()
#3  0x0181de95 in -[CALayer dealloc] ()
#4  0x0180fe23 in CALayerRelease ()
#5  0x0181e035 in CALayerFreeTransaction ()
#6  0x017b932a in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#7  0x017b946d in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#8  0x019c189b in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#9  0x019566e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#10 0x0191f1d7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#11 0x0191e840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

Comment: @jrturton #12 0x0191e761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#13 0x031541c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#14 0x03154289 in GSEventRun ()
#15 0x0094ec93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#16 0x000022e4 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff6b4) at /Users/nipinn/Downloads/ELTouchBiblelatest3 doingggg copy 30/main.m:14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the -(void)dealloc method of VersusSelectionView class.

Comment: great man,the problem is in the dealloc method.thnks verymuch